# Ajax woocommerce order tracking in popup without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce, popup

I put the order tracking via shortcode in a popup But the problem is that after clicking and sending the request, the page is reloaded and the popup closes. I want the result of the request to be displayed via Ajax in the same popup and the page not to be reloaded. I searched the whole web and could not find a way to do it. Please guide me if anyone knows how to do this.
Thank you
I found this code but it does not work properly:

```js
<div class="track-results">result will be shown here</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('from_ajax', '1');// append this to your form.

jQuery('.track_order').submit(function(event) { // catch the form's submit event
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
    jQuery.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: formData, // get the form data
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('.track-results').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

```js
$("#open").click(function(){
     $("#a").css("display","block");
     $("#b").css("display","block");
                 });


$(".cancel").click(function(){
     $("#a").fadeOut();
     $("#b").fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.main div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;

}
.main div button{
  top: 500px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.container{
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #222;
  z-index: 40000;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  animation-name: fadeIn_Container;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  
}

.modal{
  display:none;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 250px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 40001;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10%;

  animation-name: fadeIn_Modal;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
 
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.header a{
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #aaa;
}

.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

form{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

form label{
  display: block;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

form input{
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#first_label{
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#second_label{
  padding-top: 25px;
}


.footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.fotter button{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

/****MEDIA QUERIES****/

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){

  .modal{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: calc(50vw - 250px);
    margin-top: calc(50vh - 150px);
  }


  .header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
  }

  .header a{
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .content{
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
  }

  form label{
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  form input{
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  #first_label{
  padding-top: 0px;
  }

  #second_label{
    padding-top: 0px;
  }

  .footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;   
  }

  .footer button{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

}

/*LARGE SCREEN*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px){

}

/****ANIMATIONS****/

@keyframes fadeIn_Modal {
  from{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn_Container {
  from{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to{
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>
    <button id="open" onclick="openModal">Order Tracking</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="a">
  
</div>
<div class="modal" id="b">
  <div class="content">
     [woocommerce_order_tracking]
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more details. Like HTML of the popup. and if possible also share the site link.

Comment: The website is on a localhost.
I made a modal popup and put the [woocommerce_order_tracking] shortcode in it.
The order tracking form is displayed in the modal box, but when I click on the Track button, the page where I put modal popup is reloaded and I have to open modal popup again to see the tracking result.
I want the result to be displayed when modal box is open without the page being reloaded after clicking the Track button. (modal popup made with nicepage app)

Comment: Please add the HTML of the popup in your question.

Comment: I added what you said